# C++ class templates: redundancy in non-inline member functions?

Tags: c++, templates

I just started learning C++ and am looking at the tutorials online on templates.

The example I'm looking at:

```
    // class templates
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class mypair {
        T a, b;
      public:
        mypair (T first, T second)
          {a=first; b=second;}
        T getmax ();
    };

    template <class T>
    T mypair<T>::getmax ()
    {
      T retval;
      retval = a>b? a : b;
      return retval;
    }

    int main () {
      mypair <int> myobject (100, 75);
      cout << myobject.getmax();
      return 0;
    }
```

What I don't complete understand is the heading for `getmax()`:

`template <class T>
T mypair<T>::getmax ()`

A few questions:

Is it possible to include fewer or more template parameters in the member function definition than in the template class? So, if `mypair` actually took in `class T` and `class U`, then when you define `getmax`, is it possible to only pass `class T` as a template parameter?

If that's not the case, then is it redundant to have `class T` and `mypair<T>`? Since you cannot have different template parameters anyway?

Sorry if this isn't completely clear.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your template class `mypair`, you are actually declaring *three* fairly independent templates: a class template for `mypair`, a function template for `mypair::mypar` constructor and a function template for `mypair::getmax` member function. Thise templates are, of course, not completely unrelated, since `getmax` is a member of `mypair`, but they still have a significant degree of independence. They are instantiated independently, they can be specialized independently.

For example, you can explicitly specialize `mypair::getmax` without specializing `mypair`. This means that there's really no redundancy in what you are talking about. The definition of `mypair::getmax` is a definition of a [fairly] *independent* function template. The "basic" definition of that function template has to share the number and the types of its template parameters with class template (so the answer to your "less or more" question is "no"), but nevertheless they are template parameters that belong to function template.

However, you are not required to provide the "basic" definition for `mypair::getmax` at all. You already declared it in the class, so if you wish, you can omit the "basic" definition completely and proceed to defining the specializations right away

```
template<> int mypair<int>::getmax() {
  // whatever
}

template<> double mypair<double>::getmax() {
  // whatever
}
```

Comment: How would you specialize `mypair::getmax`? For example, if I wanted to specialize for `char`, would it be `template <> T mypair<T>::getmax <char> ()`?

Comment: Ok cool. So then I'm also wondering why include the `<class T>` in  the `getmax()` header? Does it add any additional information that couldn't be gotten from the specializations or generic forms? 

So to me, it seems that in the generic form, you can tell that `class T` is a parameter from `mypair<T>` and in the specialized case, you can just include `<>` to mark it as a specialization.I may be completely some point...

Comment: @user1481142 - yes, it is important information. It's possible to specialize a template with a different number of template arguments from the original template. `template<class T> class C {}; template <class T, class U> class C<std::map<T,U>> {};`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to have a different numbers of template parameters in more advanced situations. For now, though, just write it like that.